# Microsoft SQL Server INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is NULL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to get maximum allowed column length (characters count in representation, not bytes count) from MS SQL from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table. I have found that CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH can be NULL for numeric and datetime types.
I also have found three following columns in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table:

1. NUMERIC_PRECISION;
2. NUMERIC_SCALE (related to NUMERIC_PRECISION);
3. DATETIME_PRECISION;

As I understand there is always at least one not - NULL valued column existing, so we can use that columns to get maximum length. I canot find clear specification about this columns usage.
For example lets say I have DATETIME_PRECISION equals 3 for datetime type, how I can calculate characters count from that '3' using only INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables?

Comment: I feel like we've come in half way through. You have some problem (that you haven't told us about), and you *think* that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` may help you to solve it. Could you tell us what the actual problem is that needs solving?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the link you can click the datatype and if it is a string and such it will tell you max length. [Data Types Sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)

Example:
    DateTime: Character Length 19 positions minimum to 23 maximum

Answer (score 0):

You can't. the reason for that is because datetime columns don't store characters, they store a binary representation of the date and time. The number of characters that correlates to all depends on how you format that datetime. If you format it as "yyyy/MM/dd" then it will be 10 characters. If however you format it as .ToLongDateString(); then is will be different  depending on the culture and language set on your machine.

ToLongDateString() returns the following values for the provided culture/languages:

en-us: Saturday, December 5, 2009
fr-fr: samedi 5 décembre 2009
es-es: sábado, 05 de diciembre de 2009

Answer (score 0):

**Question:**  "lets say I have DATETIME_PRECISION equals 3 for datetime type, how I can calculate characters count from that '3' using only INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables?"

**Answer:**  24 *(based on some reasonable assumptions)*

Why?

First, the "3" means that the column is storing a maximum of thousandths of a second.

Second, I agree completely with @CamW's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851637/microsoft-sql-server-information-schema-columns-character-maximum-length-is-null#answer-17851905) that the count of characters depends on how you format your datetime.  So, as he indicated, you can't really calculate the characters count from the information you have provided.

However, and third, let's go a little bit further.  It seems reasonable that you would use an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for your datetime column's values.  So, for the sake of a fuller answer, let's assume:

- all your dates are between the years of 1000 and 9999, inclusive,
- you will present your datetimes as being in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (instead of some specific time zone like your own),
- and you will use the delimiters that are used by the Javascript Date.prototype.[toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)() method.

With those assumptions, your character count for your representation of any value in your column would be 24.

To see why, let's put the datetime of when you asked your question into that format.

```
2013-07-25T07:28:06.000Z    // when you asked your question

123456789012345678901234    // ruler (number of characters)
         1         2        // 

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ    // representation with specifiers
```

Perhaps coincidentally, the "3" in your example matches the precision in a standard Javascript ISO 8601 date representation:  to the thousandths of a second.  If your date precision was "4", then a similar representation that displays the available precision to the ten-thousandth of a second would be 25 characters long.   "5" = 26.   And so forth.